# unhexlify does not work as is expected or I dont know why is this happening

Tags: python, format, hex, bit

I have bits that needs to be converted in hexadecimal notation as this:

```
0b00001111 ----> '\x0F'
```

to do that I do the next:

```
unhexlify("{:02x}".format(0b00010110, 'x'))
```

and I get `b'\x16'` as expected.

but If i do

```
unhexlify("{:02x}".format(0b00110110, 'x'))
```

I get back `b'6'` as not expected. I would expect `b'\x36'`

Can someone tell me why is not happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b'6'` is the same as `b'\x36'`. `0x36` is the ASCII character code for the character `6`. The representation of a `bytes` object will only show the hex code for non-printing characters.

```
>>> print(b'6' == b'\x36')
True
```

Comment: Hi Barmar! thanks to be so quick! I do understand it now :D